# The Rolling disk paradox

Tags: paradoxes

The rolling disk is the cornerstone to nonholonomic analysis. Its nonholonomic property constitute on equal translational and rotational velocity on the contact point. However, if the speeds are equal in modulus, but opposite in direction, the contact point absolute velocity is zero. Hence, how does this point move respective the body its rollig over?

Best regards.

Comment: I am not sure I see a paradox yet. The velocity of the point touching the floor is $0$ at the moment touching the floor. (Otherwise there would be friction!) As soon as it doesn't touch the floor, its velocity is nonzero. This is no different from the case of a ball thrown in the air and reaching the highest point - its velocity at that point *is* zero, but it does not *stay* zero as its *acceleration* (change of velocity over time) is nonzero.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was not aware of the comparison. I thank you for the explanation.